# -bash: ls: command not found

Tags: bash, macos

I have setup react-native in my system.
I have mac OS X El Capitan.

After completing setup of react native, whenever i open my terminal and type command ls then, it shows "command not found".

```
export PATH="/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:$PATH"
```

After executing above two lines in my terminal, everything works fine. ls command is working after that. But once i close my terminal and again open it, ls command stops working and it shows "command not found".

I have also tried to add above two lines in .bash_profile file, but didn't get success. I don't know how to get rid of this issue.

Comment: Put them in `.bashrc` file?

Comment: `PATH` should be properly set by default. One of your shell config files (probably `.bash_profile`, maybe `.profile`) is probably incorrectly trying to add paths to it. Before you execute the above two lines, what is the output of `echo "$PATH"`?

Answer (score 20):

Add following line to you .bash_profile

```
export PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/b‌​in
```

Simply you can do it by following command

```
echo "export PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/b‌​in" >> ~/.bash_profile
```

After that please restart your terminal